# moq a method with a template parameter

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am creating a Unit test, using the moq.Mock class, to simulate the situation.
I want to mock a method with a Template param, so that i can check what is being sent to it.

```
mockGateway = new Mock<GatewayClass>();

//this one works
mockGateway.Setup(e => e.Log(It.IsAny<LogLevel>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>()))
            .Callback<LogLevelClass, Exception, string,object[]>(LogCheck);

//this one doesnt work
mockGateway.Setup(e => e.Send<RequestClass>(It.IsAny<RequestClass>()))
            .Callback<RequestClass>(SendCheck);
```

The Setup(e.. gives an 'Ambiguous invocation' Compile Error.

The RequestClass gives a compile error of 'The Type must be convertible to an IMessage in order to use as parameter TMessage in generic send,
but RequestClass implements IMessage, but the metadata when viewed doesnt show this.
as i am doing the Test in a different solution to the solution it is defined in.

```
private void LogCheck(LogLevel level, Exception ex, string str, object[] paramObjs)
{
    //do something...
}

private void SendCheck<TMessage>(TMessage message)
    where TMessage : class, IMessage,IRequestMessage, new()
{
    //do something...
}

public class RequestClass: IMessage, IRequestMessage
{
    public RequestClass();
    ...other methods..
}

public class GatewayClass : IGateway
{
    public ISynchronousRequestResult<ResultResponse> Send<TMessage>(TMessage message)
        where TMessage : class, IMessage,IRequestMessage, new()
    {
        return service.Send<ResultResponse,TMessage>(message);
    }
}
```

Can anyone show me how this should/could be done?

Comment: Can you add the definition of `RequestClass` to your question?

Comment: I can add tomorrow, but it implement IMessage.
it has a Log method that matches the LogCheck
it has a send method that matches the SendCheck parameter, except for the return is not void.
What else would you like to know?

Comment: I just want the whole picture.  Also you say the error message mentions `SendAndListen`; can you add the signature of that method as well?

Comment: Sorry the send and sendandlisten are the same method, I was just trying not to give away the actual code im working on

Comment: updated to include all classes and details.

Comment: Using the code you posted (with empty definitions for `ResultResponse`, `IMessage`, `IRequestMessage`, and `ISynchronousRequestResult<T>`), I don't have any compile errors.  Is there an overload of `Send`? I'd recommend creating a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem and then posting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check for multipul IMessage's.

I found i had a reference to a microsoft IMessage not my own.